# USING по двум полям

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы предположем: `"reestr"` и `"payments"`.
Структура первой: [... orderId, transaction_id]
Структура второй: [... transaction_id]

Необходим LEFT JOIN по полю "transaction_id", но проблема заключается в том что во второй таблице(payments), в поле transaction_id может содержаться как и transaction_id так и orderId
Поэтому запрос выдаст неточные результаты. Каким оператором возможно реализовать правильный запрос?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В описанном случае USING использовать не получится. `.. FROM reestr JOIN payments ON payments.transaction_id IN (reestr.orderId, reestr.transaction_id) ..`. *Необходим LEFT JOIN* А почему именно LEFT?

Comment: Какой результат Вы ожидаете?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, хочу узнать  записи которые есть в первой, но нету во второй, и наоборот просто проблема и заключается в путанице двух полей.

Comment: *хочу узнать записи которые есть в первой, но нету во второй, и наоборот* Для этого разумнее использовать NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Akina, возможно, но проблема тут в другом, к сожалению Ваш запрос не дает результата, т.к база вылетает по таймауту, хотя объём базы относительно небольшой( ~40к строк), возможно ли использовать другую конструкцию?